# Click to a random url on page with GeckoFX

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

I am trying to randomly Click/Navigate to a URL in my browser after the page is finished loading. I'm fairly new to C# and GeckoFX, I'm guessing the steps should be;

- Collect urls from the loaded page
- Check if they are in href and starting with http
- Navigate to a random selection from the result

So far I can get the urls but I dont know what to do next;

```
    private void LoadingFinished(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
            foreach (GeckoElement htmlElement in geckoWebBrowser1.Document.Links)
            {
                string linkItem = htmlElement.GetAttribute("href").ToString();

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following

```
var links = new List<GeckoElement>()
foreach(var link in browser.Document.Links) {
   if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(link.GetAttribute("href").ToString()))
      links.Add(link);
}
if(links.Count > 0)
   ((GeckoHtmlElement)links[new Random().Next(0, links.Count)]).Click()
else
   MessageBox.Show("No Links found")
```

Comment: When i try to use the 1st example it gives an error: Non-invocable member 'Gecko.GeckoDocument.Links' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: last one that you edited gives theese errors: 'Gecko.GeckoElement' does not contain a definition for 'Click' 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Gecko.GeckoElement>' does not contain a definition for 'add'

Comment: Now I only get a .add error "does not contain a definition for 'add'".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80044/discussion-between-c-s-and-iwan1993).